# Python Spyder console: selecting code and putting between parenthesis, brackets, quotes, ... (like in RStudio)

Tags: python, spyder

I have recently started programming a bit in Python, using Spyder as a console. A functionality I really miss - and used a lot in RStudio - is selecting code/text and then pressing parenthesis, brackets or quotes resulting in the selected code/text put between parenthesis, brackets or quotes.

E.g. select

```
some string
```

then press ", resulting in

```
"some string"
```

Can such a functionality be activated in Spyder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This functionality was added in Spyder 4, so you're probably using an older version.

Comment: I just installed Spyder 4.1.1 and it does as you say! Thank you very much and great work of you and the Spyder maintenance team :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind words!